# How to modify Mongodb query based on multiple events in qt widgets

Tags: python, mongodb, pyqt5, pymongo

I have a search window with PYQT5 which collects the data form [mongodb]. I collected the event on those widgets and based on the event, i could not able modify the search_request[query]. For example, if dateEdit event occurred the data base search_request need to consider only date. If multiple event occurs, the data base search_request [query] need to consider all values for the query.

```
def searchButtonClicked(self):
    self.search.setupUi(self)
    self.setWindowTitle("Search")
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Maiandra GD")
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.search.searchTableWidget.setFont(font)
    self.search.searchClosePushButton.clicked.connect(self.frontWindow)
    self.search.searchPushButton.clicked.connect(self.searchWindoButtonClicked)
    self.search.searchFromDateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
    self.search.searachToDateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
    self.search.searachToDateEdit.setDisabled(True)
    self.search.searchFromDateEdit.setDisabled(True)
    self.tabelHeaderResize(tableName=self.search.searchTableWidget, headerHCount=self.search.searchTableWidget.columnCount(),
                           headerVCount=self.search.searchTableWidget.rowCount())
    self.search.searchByDateCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(lambda x: self.search.searachToDateEdit.setEnabled(True) if x
                                                               else self.search.searachToDateEdit.setDisabled(True))
    self.search.searchByDateCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(lambda x: self.search.searchFromDateEdit.setEnabled(True) if x
                                                               else self.search.searchFromDateEdit.setDisabled(True))

    self.search.searchAgeFromSpinBox.clear()
    self.search.searchAgeFromSpinBox.setButtonSymbols(QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
    self.search.searchAgeFromSpinBox.wheelEvent = lambda event: None

    self.search.searchAgeToSpinBox.clear()
    self.search.searchAgeToSpinBox.setButtonSymbols(QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
    self.search.searchAgeToSpinBox.wheelEvent = lambda event: None

    serachFromDate = self.search.searchFromDateEdit.dateTime()
    serachFromDate = serachFromDate.toPyDateTime()
    self.serachFromDate = datetime.datetime.combine(serachFromDate, datetime.time.min)

    serachToDate = self.search.searachToDateEdit.dateTime()
    serachToDate = serachToDate.toPyDateTime()
    self.serachToDate = datetime.datetime.combine(serachToDate, datetime.time.max)

    self.searchbyDate = 0
    self.searchbyAge = 0
    self.searchbyArea = 0
    self.searchbyCity = 0
    self.searchbyZipcode = 0

    self.search.searchFromDateEdit.dateChanged.connect(lambda x: onSearchDateChange())
    self.search.searachToDateEdit.dateChanged.connect(lambda x: onSearchDateChange())
    self.search.searchAgeFromSpinBox.installEventFilter(self)
    self.search.searchAgeToSpinBox.installEventFilter(self)
    self.search.searchAreaLineEdit.installEventFilter(self)
    self.search.searchCityLineEdit.installEventFilter(self)
    self.search.searachZipcodeLineEdit.installEventFilter(self)

    def onSearchDateChange():
        serachFromDate = self.search.searchFromDateEdit.dateTime()
        serachFromDate = serachFromDate.toPyDateTime()
        self.serachFromDate = datetime.datetime.combine(serachFromDate, datetime.time.min)

        serachToDate = self.search.searachToDateEdit.dateTime()
        serachToDate = serachToDate.toPyDateTime()
        self.serachToDate = datetime.datetime.combine(serachToDate, datetime.time.max)
        self.searchbyDate = 1


def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if self.search.searchFromDateEdit is obj:
        if event.type() == QEvent.FocusOut:
            if self.serachFromDate > self.serachToDate:
                QMessageBox.about(self, "Warning", "Invalid Date Selection")

    if self.search.searchAgeFromSpinBox is obj or self.search.searchAgeToSpinBox is obj:
        if event.type() == QEvent.FocusOut:
            if self.search.searchAgeFromSpinBox.value() != 0 and self.search.searchAgeToSpinBox.value() != 0:
                self.searchbyAge = 1
    if self.search.searchAreaLineEdit is obj:
        if event.type() == QEvent.FocusOut:
            if self.search.searchAreaLineEdit.text() != "":
                self.searchbyArea = 1
    if self.search.searchCityLineEdit is obj:
        if event.type() == QEvent.FocusOut:
            if self.search.searchCityLineEdit.text() != "":
                self.searchbyCity = 1
    if self.search.searachZipcodeLineEdit is obj:
        if event.type() == QEvent.FocusOut:
            if self.search.searachZipcodeLineEdit.text() != "":
                self.searchbyZipcode = 1
    return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

def createSearchQuery(self):
    if self.searchbyDate == 1:
        self.search_request = {'$and': [{"Date": {"$gte": self.serachFromDate}},
                                        {"Date": {"$lte": self.serachToDate}}]}
    elif self.searchbyAge == 1:
        self.search_request = {'$and': [{"Age": {"$gte": self.search.searchAgeFromSpinBox.value()}},
                                        {"Age": {"$lte": self.search.searchAgeToSpinBox.value()}}]}
    elif self.searchbyArea == 1:
        self.search_request ={"Area": self.search.searachAreaLineEdit.text()}
    elif self.searchbyCity == 1:
        self.search_request = {"Area": self.search.searchCityLineEdit.text()}
    elif self.searchbyZipcode == 1:
        self.search_request = {"Area": self.search.searachZipcodeLineEdit.text()}


def searchWindoButtonClicked(self):
    search_request =  {"$or":[{'$or': [{"Zipcode": self.search.searachZipcodeLineEdit.text()},
                                        {"Area": self.search.searchAreaLineEdit.text()},
                                        {"City": self.search.searchCityLineEdit.text()}]},
                               {'$and':[{"Age": {"$gte":self.search.searchAgeFromSpinBox.value()}},
                                        {"Age": {"$lte":self.search.searchAgeToSpinBox.value()}}]},
                               {'$and': [{"Date": {"$gte": self.serachFromDate}},
                                         {"Date": {"$lte": self.serachToDate}}]}
                                ]
                        }
    self.search.searchTableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    for rowPosition, queryDict in enumerate(patientInfoCol.find(search_request)):
        keyList = list(queryDict.keys())
        removeKeys = ['_id', 'OP/IP', 'Time', 'Phone', 'Address', 'Vaccine_1st_dose', 'Vaccine_2nd_dose', 'Vaccine_booster', 'Symptoms']
        keyList = [e for e in keyList if e not in removeKeys]
        self.search.searchTableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)
        for column, key in enumerate(keyList):
            dict_item = QTableWidgetItem(str(queryDict[key]))
            dict_item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            if column == 1:
                dict_item = dict_item.text().split(" ")[0]
                self.search.searchTableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, column, QTableWidgetItem(dict_item))
            else:
                self.search.searchTableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, column, QTableWidgetItem(dict_item))
    else:
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Not Found", "Data Not Found.")
```

Comment: What `find_query`? There's nothing called like that in your code, which also has lots of references to objects we know nothing about.

Comment: Sorry search_request in my code. I will modify the question.

Comment: Then separate the function that only does the search using `self.search_query`, and call it whenever you set it, including when pressing the button.